# Vue Js : File upload validation (for image ,pdf , doc and excel files)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Formulate function of VueJs in my project,
FormulateInput type file is working, but know I have to put validation for the file type check but I am unable to check for mime:application for document and excel files.
Validation for only pdf and image is working...

Any guidance on setting up validation using formulated forms in VueJs would be helpful.

```html
<FormulateInput
  type="file"
  input-class="formulate-form-control"
  name="filename"
  id="fileid"
  validation-name="filecheck"
  accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx"
  validation = "mime:application/pdf"
/>
```

Comment: Did you try the correct mime types? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/12843923

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn yes, it's working for pdf (validation = "mime:application/pdf")
but not able to set validation for doc and excel
 (validation = "mime:application/doc,.docx") not working

Comment: for .doc it's mime:application/msword, that's why I posted the link ;)

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn validation = "mime:application/msword, application/pdf" ...tried this and other formats too, but its not working for me in VueJs

Comment: Looks fine to me. And pdf is also not working now? Maybe, your doc file is not a good one. You can try it with .docx and validation = "mime:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf".

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn tried all the extensions and combinations. Up till my search it seams that formulated input doesn't have support file type for doc or docx...
as for pdf and image file upload is working...

https://vueformulate.com/guide/validation/#available-rules

#vuejs

Comment: That might be.. One step back: I wouldn't do this validation in front-end, but at the backend endpoint where you are sending your form to. E.g. the POST endpoint. It's also more secure against abuse because your Vue Form can be manipulated on client-side.

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn I have a check at the back-end, but initially, I can't allow everything to be uploaded ( though it might be breached) but to give users a better experience its required and most importantly front-end check is always a good process.

Comment: If it's a synchronous request, you could give the backend validation error back to your form. But I understand your point. If the mime type validation in Vue doesn't work, you can try with the accept property which also takes mime types, see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept). This is browser standard, so this _should_ also work also in Vue? `accept = ".pdf,.doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` Sorry that I can't help you more, I am not too familiar with Vue, more Angular fraction here.

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn Thanks and appreciate your time, have tried that too.